# How to manage a Docker container with port mapping?

Tags: iptables, docker

I installed [the ELK Docker container](http://elk-docker.readthedocs.org/#installation).

I run it with these parameters:

```
sudo docker run -p 5601:5601 -p 9200:9200 -p 5044:5044 -p 5000:5000 -it --name elk sebp/elk
```

Check check:

```
sudo docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                      NAMES
4f42137c954d        sebp/elk:latest     "/usr/local/bin/star   22 hours ago        Up 22 hours         0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5044->5044/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5601->5601/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 9300/tcp   elk
```

Jo, looks good.

Here is the external interface of the KVM guest, in which the Docker containers reside:

marius@elk:~$ ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:15:cf:f2
          inet addr:192.168.100.134  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

But port 5044 (for Elastic Beats e.g.) is closed in the KVM network interface:

```
marius@elk:~$ nc -v 192.168.100.134 5044
nc: connect to 192.168.100.134 port 5044 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

The reason for this appears to be, that I created chaos:

```
marius@elk:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.4           tcp dpt:5000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.4           tcp dpt:5044
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.4           tcp dpt:5601
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.4           tcp dpt:9200
```

And the new IP of the Docker container after a restart is `172.17.42.1` and `0.4`

marius@elk:~$ /sbin/ifconfig 
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a6:3d:01:38:7a:6a
          inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0

So, how do I restart / manage a Docker container in a way, so that I don't run into IPtables conflicts

And how do I fix this without creating a Docker / IPtables chaos each time? I don't want to manually flush away Docker's iptables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost - this is because you're operating under a bit of a misconception. Docker containers have dynamic IP addressing within the docker network. You are asking for pain if you try and rely on that being static.

So don't - just get used to the idea that whilst containers have to have IP addresses to work, you shouldn't ever refer to them directly. You have a number of ways of avoiding this:

- `docker inspect` + pass environment variables to containers.
- With newer docker (1.10+) you have a [name service](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/)
- haproxy can dynamically reroute traffic to a range of IP addresses, so you can use something like `haproxy` + `confd` + `etcd` to 'detect' container locations, and dynamically add new entries to the haproxy configuration.